# Creating Collection in Azure Search Service using Indexer

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I am using indexer to sync data from my SQL Database to Azure Search Service. I have a field in my SQL View, which contains XML data. The Column contains a list of string. The corresponding field in my Azure Search Service Index in a Collection(Edm.String).
On checking some documentations, I found that Indexer does not change Xml(SQL) to Collection(Azure Search).
Is there any workaround as to how I can get create the Collection from the Xml data?

p.s I am extracting the data from a View, so I can change the Xml to JSON if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE on October 17, 2016:** Azure Search now automatically converts a string coming from a database to an Collection(Edm.String) field **if the data represents a JSON string array:** for example, `["blue", "white", "red"]`

**Old response:** great timing, we just added a new "field mappings" feature that allows you to do this. This feature will be deployed sometime early next week. I will post a comment on this thread when this is rolled out in all datacenters.

To use it, you indeed need to use JSON. Make sure your source column contains a JSON array, for example ["hello" "world"]. Then, update your indexer definition to contain the new fieldMappings property:

```
"fieldMappings" : [ { "sourceFieldName" : "YOUR_SOURCE_FIELD", "targetFieldName" : "YOUR_TARGET_FIELD", "mappingFunction" : { "name" : "jsonArrayToStringCollection" } } ]
```

NOTE: You'll need to use API version 2015-02-28-Preview to add fieldMappings.

HTH,
Eugene

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Its going to be very helpful for us.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to check on the progress of the above feature. When can we expect an update regarding this feature?

Comment: Hi Pratik, this has now been rolled out in all regions. Give it a try and let us know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I am actually getting the following error: Search request failed: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: index : The property 'fieldMappings' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2015_02_28_Preview.IndexDefinition'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.\r\n"}}

Comment: Looks like you're doing a PUT on indexes instead of indexeRs .

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked it. It works as expected, the column containing Json Array in the database is correctly mapped to Collection (Edm.String).

Comment: I just have one more question. I am using Microsoft.Azure.Search .Net Sdk package; has this feature been incorporated in the Sdk package also?

Comment: Hi Pratik, this isn't exposed in the SDK yet, because it's still in a preview version. Eventually we'll have a preview SDK as well.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for all your help. It was a great help for us.