# Define AzureSearch index fieldmappings in c# code

Tags: azure, search, indexer, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to programatically define in C# the fieldmappings between a JSON object and the Azure Search index. I have found the explanation on how to do this In Javascript here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-index-json-blobs/

```
 "fieldMappings" : [ 
{ "sourceFieldName" : "/article/text", "targetFieldName" : "text" },
{ "sourceFieldName" : "/article/datePublished", "targetFieldName" : "date" },
{ "sourceFieldName" : "/article/tags", "targetFieldName" : "tags" }
]
```

however I need the c# equivalent code. I have tried so far:

```
      var index = new
      {
           name = "testindex",
           fields = new []
           { 
              //...
           },
           fieldMappings = new[]
           {
              new { sourceFieldName = "/status/text", targetFieldName = "text"}
           }
      }
```

but this code crashes with the exception

```
{"Azure Search request failed:{\"error\":{\"code\":\"\",\"message\":\"The request is invalid. Details: index : The property 'fieldMappings' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2015_02_28.IndexDefinition'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.\\r\\n\"}}"}
```

Any suggestions on how I can programatically in C# code define these field mappings? IN addition, should these fieldMappings be defined inside the indexer of the index definition? Thank you!

@LaterEdit: From this article [Creating Collection in Azure Search Service using Indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676937/creating-collection-in-azure-search-service-using-indexer) I found that these mappings have to be defined on the indexer, but it is still the case that if I add them when defining the indexer the property fieldMappings does not exist.

```
  var indexer = new
  {
      name = "textixr",
      dataSourceName = "testsdocdb",
      schedule = new { interval = "PT5M" }, // every 5 minutes
      targetIndexName = "test",
      fieldMappings = new []
      {
          new { sourceFieldName = "/status/text", targetFieldName = "text" }
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use api-version 2015-02-28-**Preview**. Field mappings are not available in 2015-02-28.

By the way, field mappings with JSON pointers (such as `/status/text`) can only be used when indexing JSON blobs with blob indexer. They cannot be used with the DocumentDB indexer. To project nested properties with DocumentDB, use a SQL-like query in container.query property of the datasource definition. For more info on DocumentDB indexer, please check out [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-search-indexer/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. 2015-02-28-Preview does not give the error. However, I am not sure how to use a Sql-like query in container.query property. Could you maybe give me an example, or point me to an article where this is mentioned?

Comment: You need to use a SQL query when defining the datasource to flatten your documents, something like SELECT c.id, c._ts, **c.status.text AS text** FROM Collection c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark. The article I linked to has examples.

Comment: Thank you! I am currently creating the DocumentDb database, the AzureSearch indexer and indexer programatically in C#, is there a way to call this syntax in C#?

Comment: Are you referring to specifying a query for a datasource using .NET SDK? Yes, use [DataContainer.Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.search.models.datacontainer.aspx) property: dataSource.Container.Query = "a query".